# Run a Workflow/Plugin after every solution import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing some code that will update the reference of the Business Units after the deployment of a new solution.

After a solution import all the references point to the Dev's Business Unit Guid, so, for instance, every view that refers to them is empty.

Manually updating those references is time consuming and boring. That's why I am writing some code that does the trick.

The code works, but it would be much better if I could add it inside a Custom Workflow Activity or a Plugin and have them run after every solution import automatically.

Is it possible or am I just daydreaming?

Comment: Where are the Business Unit guids being stored in the solution being imported?  Is it in your code, in a workflow or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `Import` and `ImportAll` message you can register your plugins on, however I have never used them so I'm not sure how they work.

I have registered plugins on `Publish` and `PublishAll` messages before.  You can use those messages and they will run after you publish an entity/resource or publish all the changes respectively.